# How do I remove a duplicate MainStoryboard.storyboard ((null)) file?

Tags: ios, internationalization, storyboard, xcode4.6

I made some changes to my app for internationalization before reading the manual (I know, I know... ).  I think I have recovered, but am left with what appears to be an extra MainStoryboard.storyboard file (the one with ((null))).  They appear to be exactly the same; question is:  how do I remove the one with ((null))?

[image: multiple MainStoryboard.storyboard files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up (or use your version control), delete it, run and see what happens. Clean before building and remove the old version from the Simulator or your device (to prevent a cached version from confusing things).

Comment: Sound strange, maybe something's corrupted. Try finding the file in the Finder and deleting it there, or restarting Xcode.

Comment: Not in Finder (at least under that name with the ((null)

Comment: Delete the storyboard in Xcode (without "Move to Trash") and then re-add it to Xcode from the Finder?

Comment: Yes, something is corrupted; it's going to be a job to find it... thanks for your time.